# How to persist Entity containing Hstore field using OpenJPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, openjpa

Using OpenJPA implementation (PostgreSQL) :

I'm trying to persist an Entity containg an Hstore field :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gfx_properties")
@NamedQuery(name = "GfxProperties.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM GfxProperties g")
public class GfxProperties implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_gfx_properties")
    private Integer idGfxProperties;

    @Lob @Persistent @Column(name = "key_values")
    private String keyValues;

    public Map<String, String> getKeyValues() {
        return keyValues != null ? HStoreConverter.fromString(keyValues) : new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setKeyValues(Map<String, String> keyValues) {
        try {
            if (keyValues == null) {
                this.keyValues = null;
            } else {
                this.keyValues = HStoreConverter.toString(keyValues);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work, i have an exception telling me that : the column « key_values » is of type hstore but the expression is of type oid.

Please help me

Comment: Do you must use OpenJPA or is Hibernate an alternative?

Comment: saddly I must use OpenJPA

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MapToStringConveter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> attribute) {
        return HStoreConverter.toString(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return HStoreConverter.fromString(dbData);
    }
}
```

And then use it in your entity:

```
@Convert(converter = MapToStringConveter.class)
@Column(name = "key_values")
private String keyValues;
```